# serial.tools.list_ports.comports() is only returning one item

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a script that will read from comports, however, it doesn't seem to be working as intended. When running `serial.tools.list_ports.comports()`, it only returns one item, `COM1`. And I know for a fact that my computer has more than one USB port; 10 in fact. So I don't understand why it's only returning one item.

I've tried running the script as administrator, however, the results were the same as running it without admin.

```
def get_ports():
    return serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
```

However, all I get is:

```
>>> get_ports()
[<serial.tools.list_ports_common.ListPortInfo object at 0x00C8FFB0>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USB ports are not COM ports.

[COM ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_(hardware_interface)) are serial interfaces, which have disappeared from modern PCs since quite some time. Unless you have an old PC that still has a serial port, COM1 is a virtual port created by a driver, e.g. for a USB-to-Serial device.